# Why two consecutive casting change an integer number?

Tags: c++

I wrote the below program :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int i =123456789;
   float f=i;
   int j=f;
   std::cout<<"j-i ="<<j-i;
}
```

As far as we know, float numbers has at least 4 byte length in the memory. and `123456789` in decimal is equal with `0x75BCD15` in hexadecimal and this is less than 4 byte. So I why when I run the above program, the output is not `0`?

```
ap1019@sharifvm:~$ ./a.out
j-i = 3
```

Comment: `float numbers has at least 4 byte length` really? I don't think that standard does say so - as always does.

Comment: Just because `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)` doesn't mean that they are equal when it comes to things like precision. You might want to read about the [IEEE floating point formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Formats), which is the most common format for floating point values on computers.

Comment: A simple, but good enough, and most importantly accessible introduction to floating point numbers is [Barteks introduction to floating point numbers](http://2013.jsconf.eu/speakers/bartek-szopka-everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-numbers-and-you-didnt-know-you-could-ask.html) talk at jsconf. It actually covers JS but 99% of the talk is about the standard for floating point numbers so its relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `float` only has 23 bits of precision (*). The other 9 bits are needed for the sign and the exponent. This means that after 16,777,216 you get holes in the "whole numbers" float range.

(*) Actually 24 bits, but only 23 bits need to be stored; the first bit is implied by the exponent.